# Modify chart series tooltip #ValY before displaying in vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, charts, tooltip

Using ToolTip I am displaying data point values on a line chart. The ToolTip display was activated with the following code:

```
Chart1.Series("Wtr").ToolTip = "#VALY"
```

This works as it should but I need to perform some math on #VALY" before ToolTip displays it. Basically, I need to divide it by a fixed factor to reduce the value to a percentage (e.g. #VALY / fixed factor.) I've tried assigning #VALY to a variable but I can't get the value of #VALY.

I also tried using the ToolTip Popup event but it doesn't fire when hovering over a chart series. ToolTip Keywords might be the solution but I can't find a way to assign a fixed value to a Keyword.

I've spent several weeks researching and playing with this but haven't hit on a solution as yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a Windows 7 / VB.Net 2012 platform.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs to know, i finally solved the problem myself. I created a dataview on my datatable and used it to databind the columns in the datatable. I was then able to select any column I wanted for my tooltip. In this case I wanted to display "WtrRaw" when hovering over a "Wtr" data point.

prdView = New Dataview(dtProd)
ChartProd.Series("Wtr").Points.DataBind(prdView, "X-Axis", "Wtr", ToolTip = "WtrRaw")